# Using System.load vs library set as agent

Tags: java, jvm, jvmti

I made a simple library for measuring the size of a given object. The library is 
accessed through JNI from a Java class. It's specifically designed for Hotspot, thus it uses the JVMTI and it calls `GetObjectSize`.

My question is, what's the better solution?

1. To load the library using `System.load("library")` or
2. to set the library as an agent and explicitly load it by issuing the java command with the agent option.

All similar examples I've seen so far employ the agent function:

- [Determine Java class size from JNI jclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978566/determine-java-class-size-from-jni-jclass)
- [How to calbulate the size of an object](http://grokbase.com/t/struts/user/0478sdvqzw/ot-how-to-calculate-the-size-of-an-object)

In what way is that more efficient than just loading the library?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need this?Why aren't you using a memory profiler to find the size of your objects?

Comment: A memory profiler would be too heavy. I'm working to extend a tool that does formal heap consumption analysis of methodes/classes. The formulas are dependent on the size of the instance of classes. Right now, this size is mentioned formally, as (Sizeof String instance) or (Sizeof Object instance). What I'm trying to do is specialize for each JVM implementation. Basically, replace the terms with actual numbers. There already is a specialization for one VM implementation. The plan is to add specializations for various VMs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantage of command-line injection, is that the agent is loaded together with the Virtual Machine. You can inject the agent into every Java program without modifying the program. With `System.load` that this done at the point of invocation. You can react to a bigger set of callbacks, for instance there is a [VM Initialization Event](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html#VMInit). If you use `System.load` that event is bygone.

As a result, I do not believe that using command-line injection is so much more efficient in a cetain way, but rather more effective for some use cases.

Comment: Sorry for the one year belated answer check. Thanks for the explanation. I ended using the library function, since in my case, using a library to calculate object memory consumption, the agent provided minimal advantages.